# No macro in summary of synthesis on Xilinx FPGA

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

I am synthesizing my vhdl code in ISE 14.7 (Xilinx) targeting Virtex 6 board.

One of the modules I am synthesizing is giving the following:

```
Synthesizing Unit (blk_combined). 
Related source file is "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\project\blk_combined.vhd". 
Found 20-bit register for signal (y). 
Summary:no macro. 
Unit (blk_combined) synthesized.
```

Knowing that  is an output port. What does it mean to have no macro inferred in summary, although this block contains multiplication,addition, subtraction...? Is it normal practice to have no macro in summary even if the block is doing some arithmetical operations on input?

Comment: [XST Synthesis Overview](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/ise_c_using_xst_for_synthesis.htm) *During HDL synthesis, XST analyzes the HDL code and attempts to infer specific design building blocks or macros (such as MUXes, RAMs, adders, and subtractors) for which it can create efficient technology implementations. To reduce the amount of inferred macros, XST performs a resource sharing check. This usually leads to a reduction of the area as well as an increase in the clock frequency.*

Answer (score 1):

Unless arithmetic operations and registers are implemented in the submodules of `blk_combined`, they are expected to be listed there.

Here is an example.

```
Synthesizing Unit <mult_9x9>.
    Related source file is "../rtl/mult_9x9.v".
    Found 9x9-bit multiplier for signal <out>.
    Summary:
    inferred   1 Multiplier(s).
Unit <mult_9x9> synthesized.

Synthesizing Unit <multiplier_top>.
    Related source file is "../rtl/multiplier_top.v".
    Found 9-bit register for signal <in0_reg>.
    Found 9-bit register for signal <in1_reg>.
    Found 18-bit register for signal <out_reg>.
    Summary:
    inferred  36 D-type flip-flop(s).
Unit <multiplier_top> synthesized.
```

If there are no arithmetic operations and registers, "no macro" is very normal.

```
Synthesizing Unit <add024>.
    Related source file is "../rtl/add024.v".
    Summary:
    no macro.
Unit <add024> synthesized.
```

The first thing that can be done is checking the following part of the same log file.

```
=========================================================================
HDL Synthesis Report

Macro Statistics
# Multipliers                                          : 1
 9x9-bit multiplier                                    : 1
# Registers                                            : 3
 18-bit register                                       : 1
 9-bit register                                        : 2

=========================================================================
```

If some macros are still missing, RTL Schematic in Xilinx ISE may help. Since this schematic is created before the optimization stage, it should reflect what the RTL contains.